# Does server only CA certificate with Mosquitto encrypt messages from the client to the server

Tags: ssl, mosquitto

This is probably a stupid question, but, in the [Mosquitto.conf](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) documentation on SSL says,

> If false, the SSL/TLS component of the client will verify the server but there is no requirement for the client to provide anything for the server: authentication is limited to the MQTT built in username/password

If one chooses this particular protocol does it mean the encryption is only one way, i.e. only broker traffic to the client is encrypted, or is traffic encrypted in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

if you set `require_certificate` config to false only the server(broker) will be authenticated. If you want to authenticate the client as well, you have to set the said config to true.

if it's set to true, client has to send the certificates to the broker, therefore enabling mutual authentication.